# Is it possible to set the div width in html?

Tags: html

I have the following code

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.text
{
  width:10%;
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="text">1234567890123456789</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the div contents are displayed outside the div,
is there any way such that i can put the text displayed out of the div in the next line, also i don't want to display a scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to break the text up character-wise, not by word. It's being rendered as a really long word (the same way it's done in books), so force the browser to break it even if there are no spaces:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

Line wrapping is possible, just have to set the 'white-space' condition to normal.

See: http://www.1keydata.com/css-tutorial/wrap.php

Answer (score 0):

You may find that the reason the text is not wrapping is that you have no spaces in your div contents: try something like 1234 6789 1234 6789 and see if it wraps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to break the continuous text using following code after every character.

```
<WBR>   --This works for Mozilla and other browsers
&Shy;   --For IE you need to add
```

In your example: 1234567890123456789

The text should be like this in code behind: 1234567890123456789

While rendering the text, the browser will hide this  / ­ tag.

the problem with using these tag is: When you select the text on browser and copy it to notepad, you will find a '-' character is added in between every character.

Please check whether it works for you.